# Is there a way to use fmt::output_file to write wstring to a file?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17, visual-studio-2019, fmt

I am trying to write formatted wstring logs to file using fmt. I can do it by using `fmt::format(...)` and `fmt::vprint` but I want to use `fmt::output_file` to do it, however I am getting compile error.

Below code shows two ways that are working and the last one that does not work.

```
...
#include <fmt/format.h>
#include <fmt/xchar.h>
#include <fmt/os.h>


template <typename... Args>
static void Helper(const std::wstring& str, const Args&... args)
{
    std::filesystem::create_directories("C:\\Logs");
    std::filesystem::path file_path("C:\\Logs\\dll");

    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>> converter;
    auto file_path_utf8 = converter.to_bytes(file_path.wstring());
    // Method 1 Working
    std::wofstream f_stream(file_path.string().c_str(), std::ios::app);
    f_stream << fmt::format(str, args...);
    
    // Method 2 Working
    std::FILE* file = std::fopen(file_path.string().c_str(), "a");
    fmt::vprint(file, str.c_str(), fmt::make_wformat_args(args...));
    std::fclose(file);
    
    // Method 3 NOT WORKING
    auto file = fmt::output_file(file_path.string().c_str(), fmt::file::WRONLY | fmt::file::CREATE | fmt::file::APPEND);
    file.print(str, args...);
}
```

With method 3 I am getting the following compilation error.

```
error C2664: 'void fmt::v9::ostream::print<>(fmt::v9::basic_format_string<char>)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'const std::wstring' to 'fmt::v9::basic_format_string<char>'
```

The example for this `print` member function is given on https://fmt.dev/latest/api.html#system-apis

How do I make `file.print` work with `const std::wstring` when its expecting `fmt::v9::basic_format_string<char>` by default?

[image: Example mentioned on the API Ref Page]

Comment: It seems that instead of calling a member function (which seems to only work with the `basic_format_string<char>`), you should use the free function like `fmt::print(file, str, args...);`.

Comment: I tried that already. Doesn't work.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/axErW9q6M This should work.

Comment: It does not. `error C2665: 'fmt::v9::print': none of the 2 overloads could convert all the argument types`.
Could it be that `args...`  have some type which is causing the compiler error?

Comment: The docs state void fmt::print(std::ostream &os, format_string<T...> fmt, T&&... args). You are missing std::ostream in your code, you should add this parameter.

Comment: Hi, I have added the screenshot of the function from API Reference. That is the function I am trying to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fmt::output_file` is an experimental optimized API and as such it intentionally doesn't support wide strings because the latter would require transcoding. If you want to write wide strings you can do it with `fmt::print` and standard `FILE` or `ostream`:

```
#include <fmt/xchar.h>
#include <filesystem>

template <typename... T>
void helper(const std::wstring& str, T&&... args) {
  std::filesystem::path file_path("path/to/logs");
  auto file = fopen(file_path.string().c_str(), "w");
  fmt::print(file, fmt::runtime(str), std::forward<T>(args)...);
  fclose(file); // Better use RAII instead.
}

int main() {
  helper(L"{}", 42);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/aooajYWT9